# Overwrite previous print() python 3.9

Tags: python, printing, overwrite

I realise there are a number of answers to this question already online, however when trying \r it only goes to the end of the last line, rather to the very start of that line.

```
print("hello", end="")
print("\rthere")
```

ends up with:

```
hellothere
```

I've also tried

```
print("hello", end="\r")
print("there")
```

but with the same results. Everywhere I've looked has said that this should leave me with just 'there' which is what I want

Comment: If you need only "there" then why would you print "hello" in first place?

Comment: Not all consoles support a carriage return overwriting the line. Try other consoles. Also, don't try this in a IDE console. For whatever reason, consoles in IDEs rarely support features like this.

Comment: Sorry, bad example. I'm trying to make a progress bar of sorts.. will update question

Comment: This should work in an ordinary terminal emulator.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that was the issue! Any idea why it's not supported in IDE consoles?

Comment: You might try using multiple ```"\b"``` to back up and then overwrite the previous output.

Comment: Because writing a real terminal emulator is hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Turns out as I was trying this in the IDE console which doesn't support the carriage return it just didn't create a new line, rather than returning to the start of the previous line